# Quartz.net loses default settings when publishing with Trim unused code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, quartz.net

We use Quartz.net to handle jobs in a .NET Core 7 console application. It runs fine in Visual Studio while debugging. After publishing, it throws this exception:

> Unknown configuration property 'quartz.scheduler.instanceName'

We don't set any property and Quartz.net should use its own default value.

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
_scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
_scheduler.JobFactory = _serviceProvider.GetService<IJobFactory>();
await _scheduler.Start();
```

But why it tells that it does not have it? After investigating, I find that when publishing, if I enable "Trim unused code", it produces this error. If I disable "Trim unused code", it is fine.

I want to know what it does by "Trim with code", does it delete some settings inside Quartz.dll?